# Spring Security 5.0 - пытаюсь перенаправить пользователей на разные страницы в зависимости от роли

Tags: spring-security

При входе Админа - переходит на restaurants и всё работает гладко, при входе Юзера - выдаёт 404 ошибку. Обе jsp лежат в одной директории. Не могу понять, в какую сторону копать.

web.xml

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

spring-security.xml

```
<http pattern="/resources/**" security="none"/>
<http pattern="/webjars/**" security="none"/>

<http pattern="/rest/**" use-expressions="true" name="restSecurityFilterChain" create-session="stateless">
    <http-basic/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/rest/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>

<beans:bean name="noopEncoder" class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.NoOpPasswordEncoder"/>

<http>
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="isAnonymous()"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/admin/**" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
    <form-login login-page="/login"
                authentication-failure-url="/login?error=true"
                login-processing-url="/spring_security_check"
                authentication-success-handler-ref="customAuthenticationHandler"/>
    <logout logout-success-url="/login"/>
    <csrf disabled="true"/>
</http>

<beans:bean id="customAuthenticationHandler" class="ru.neustupov.votingforrestaurants.util.CustomAuthenticationHandler" />

<authentication-manager>
    <authentication-provider>
        <password-encoder ref="noopEncoder"/>
        <user-service>
            <user name="user@yandex.ru" password="password" authorities="ROLE_USER"/>
            <user name="admin@yandex.ru" password="admin" authorities="ROLE_ADMIN"/>
        </user-service>
    </authentication-provider>
</authentication-manager>
```

Создал CustomAuthenticationHandler.java

```
public class CustomAuthenticationHandler extends SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler {

@Override
public void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
                                    Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
    String userTargetUrl = "profileRestaurants";
    String adminTargetUrl = "restaurants";
    Set<String> roles = AuthorityUtils.authorityListToSet(authentication.getAuthorities());
    if (roles.contains("ROLE_ADMIN")) {
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, adminTargetUrl);
    }
    else if(roles.contains("ROLE_USER")) {
        getRedirectStrategy().sendRedirect(request, response, userTargetUrl);
    }
    else {
        super.onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        return;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Сбросьте контроллер для начала.

Comment: @RomanC дело действительно было в контроллере )

Comment: Вы можете почитать что такое [ошибка 404](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404).